# Auto-complete in WPF - Making a popup unfocusable

Tags: wpf, autocomplete, focus

I'm trying to create a custom UserControl that will mimic auto-complete as it works within Intellisense using WPF. I'm using a TextBox and a Popup containing a ListBox within my control.

I want to be able to keep keyboard focus set on the TextBox irrespective of whether or not the auto-completion popup is open so that a user can continue typing whilst simultaneously using up/down controls or the mouse to select elements in the popup to autocomplete the text. Is there any way this can be done in WPF?

Comment: a [quick search of google](http://www.google.com/search?q=wpf+autocomplete) reveals many samples, tutorials, etc. Pick one and run with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out my article on CodeProject, it addresses the issue of the popup specifically.
[A Reusable WPF Autocomplete TextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/autocomplete_textbox.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I did end up using your autocomplete box as a reference.